# My form is submitting both form functions

Tags: jquery, html, forms

If I hit Email it submits Email form ok once, if I hit Alt it submits also the form ok once.
But if I hit Email and then later in the same session I hit Alt, it submits both the Email and Alt submit form functions

```html
<form id="main" method="post">

  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail">
  <input type="hidden" name="alt" id="alt">
  <br>
    <button id="btnEmail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mainModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Email</button>
  <button id="btnAlt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mainModal" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Alt</button>
</form>
```

jQuery functions:

```html
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#inputEmail").change(function() {
    $('#alt').val($(this).val());
});

$("#inputEmail").click( function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "inputemail.jsp",
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    { 
      $(".modal-body .content").html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert("error");
    }
    });
  });
});

$("#alt").click( function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "alt.jsp",
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    { 
      $(".modal-body .content").html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert("error");
    }
    });
  });
});

});
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Maybe you need to clear the form after send your data...

Comment: Where is the `.modal-body .content`element that you're replacing? And what is your server answering or replacing that elements content with?